# What are the most active languages on Code Review

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, statistics

Normally I ask and answer questions on C++. And the responses are reasonable.

But recently I asked question for review of my JavaScript (as I actually need a lot of help here). But I got a lot less help than I expected (I was expecting more people to be reviewing JavaScript than C++ given the relative popularity of the languages).

Is there an easy way to find the relative "popularity" / engagement for each language on this site?

Comment: For asked question you could just check the [Tags](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags) sorted by "Popular" you will see which tag has the most question asked.

Comment: Here is a [sede query](https://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/1576730/number-of-questions-and-answers-in-a-specific-tag-per-year?TagName=javascript) which shows the question and answer count by year for a specific tag.

Comment: To expand on Heslacher's tag point: "C" "10 asked this month, 199 this year" & "C++" "9 asked this week, 37 this month" vs "JavaScript"  "5 asked this week, 19 this month".

Answer (score 3):

Based purely on usage, the easiest way is to look at the [Tags](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags) and ignore anything not a language. The top 5 happen to be languages and include both C++ and JavaScript.

| Language | Questions | This month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Python | 15243 | 40 |
| Java | 10854 | 13 |
| C# | 10013 | 13 |
| JavaScript | 9648 | 12 |
| C++ | 9322 | 25 |

Popularity is not a well-defined metric if we don't consider purely the amount of usage.

One way to look at engagement, would be looking at the questions and accepted answer percentage (query borrowed from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/56120/269301)). Look at the top 200 tags, discarding anything not strictly a language or language version:

| Tag | Questions | With an accept answer | % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [c++20](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) | 261 | 175 | 67 |
| [haskell](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haskell) | 1079 | 691 | 64 |
| [perl](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/perl) | 226 | 146 | 64 |
| [python-2.x](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x) | 1236 | 789 | 63 |
| [c++11](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) | 1720 | 1088 | 63 |
| [c](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c) | 3879 | 2449 | 63 |
| [bash](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bash) | 803 | 499 | 62 |
| [objective-c](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/objective-c) | 368 | 231 | 62 |
| [ruby](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ruby) | 1623 | 1016 | 62 |
| [c++17](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) | 559 | 344 | 61 |
| [python-3.x](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) | 5298 | 3261 | 61 |
| [c++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) | 9319 | 5617 | 60 |
| [c#](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%23) | 10015 | 6106 | 60 |
| [f#](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/f%23) | 360 | 218 | 60 |
| [python](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) | 15240 | 9005 | 59 |
| [c++14](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) | 475 | 281 | 59 |
| [ecmascript-6](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) | 673 | 401 | 59 |

While ECMAScript is basically JavaScript (ES6), the tag [javascript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript) itself is at 54%. That's scoring slightly better than languages like [vba](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vba) (53%) and [go](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/go) (48%), but definitely not at the top. The other top-5 language not mentioned yet, [java](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java), is at 57%.

Comparing [javascript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and [c++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) over time directly (thanks to [Heslacher](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10883/what-are-the-most-active-languages-for-code-review#comment21583_10883) for the query):

[javascript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript):
[image: JavaScript Q&A 2010-2023]

[c++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b):
[image: C++ Q&A 2010-2023]

| Year | Q JS | A JS | Q C++ | A C++ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2012 | 554 | 849 | 272 | 476 |
| 2013 | 735 | 978 | 432 | 713 |
| 2014 | 1238 | 2031 | 930 | 2041 |
| 2015 | 1248 | 1704 | 1091 | 1920 |
| 2016 | 1272 | 1532 | 1199 | 1804 |
| 2017 | 1126 | 1471 | 1185 | 1831 |
| 2018 | 805 | 1106 | 1025 | 1846 |
| 2019 | 832 | 1087 | 832 | 1287 |
| 2020 | 705 | 871 | 835 | 1256 |
| 2021 | 447 | 577 | 616 | 1100 |
| 2022 | 308 | 358 | 479 | 784 |

I'll leave any conclusion about which the more popular language is up to you, but those are the numbers.